# Auto Refresh of a page

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a web page consisting of a dropdown menu. What i want is the contents of other dropdown menus present in the page must change according to what has been selected in the first dropdown box. For example if a dropdown consists of Degree as its element. If i select Degree element then another dropdown must show only degree courses. This must happen automatically without clicking any button. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You'll probably need to code this kind of behavior with JavaScript.  Using the jQuery library will help.

Comment: @Keoki: Can u plz point me to some resources where i can find examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make this a comment, but I do not have commenting abilities.  You are going to want to use `$.post` with jquery and ajax to accomplish this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ .  Ajax with JQuery is not difficult to do.

You will want to use the onchange event of the first drop down to use a jquery ajax `$.post` call to post to the server, passing the selection from the drop down as a parameter.  The page that it post's to should us `GET` to get the selected attribute from the drop down, and then retrieve ( from the database or where ever) the options that go into the second drop down, based on the parameter.  The code should be written out to the page.  The jquery ajax call has a way to get the response and let you define a custom function to be run once the post returns. The return should be what you had written out to the page, and then you can just update the second drop down list with the returned data inside this function.

I hope this helps!